# how to delete a file matching a pattern in linux

Tags: linux, find

How do I find a file matching a pattern and then delete all of it? 
Something like

```
find -name 'pattern%'
```

Then how to delete all of found entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Deleting Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html) of the `find` manual:

> **10.1.6 Using the -delete action**
>
> The most efficient and secure method of solving this problem is to use the ‘-delete’ action:
>
> ```
> find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -delete
> ```

So, just call `find -name 'pattern%' -delete`.

Comment: Thanks dude. Can i ask another question here in the comment please? 
what does this line mean: grep foo bar

Comment: That'd mean you search `foo` in a file called `bar`. But this shouldn't be hard to find out if you read the manuals of the commands/programs you're using. See `man grep` (and `man find` for the answer to your initial question).